# Firebase auth.currentUser is null when loading the page, user loaded when authstatechange called after some milli seconds of page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using React with Firebase to develop a small web app.
To take care of authentication, I am using context API and inside context I am adding loggedin user details.

> AuthProvider.tsx

```
const AuthProvider: React.FC = props => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<IAuthContext>(authInitialState);
  console.log("Inside AuthProvider");
  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged( user => {
      console.log("Auth State changed and user is ----->", user);
      if (user) {
        console.log("User value updated to the context")
        setState({
            ...authInitialState,
          isAuthenticated:!!user,
          permissions:[],
          user:user
        });
      }
      const stateChange = {
        ...authInitialState,
        isAuthenticated: !!user,
        user
      };
      // if (!user) {
        return setState(stateChange);
      // }
    });
  }, []);
  console.log("Rendering AuthProvider", state);
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={state}>{props.children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default AuthProvider;
```

> AuthConsumer.tsx

```
const withAuthContext = (
  Component: React.ComponentClass<any> | React.FunctionComponent<any>
) => {
  console.log("Rendering AuthConsumer for ");
  return (props: any) => (
    <AuthContext.Consumer>
      {context => <Component {...props} context={context} />}
    </AuthContext.Consumer>
  );
};

export default withAuthContext;
```

> PrivateRoute.tsx

```
interface PrivateRouteProps extends RouteProps {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
    component: any;
    context: IAuthContext;
}

const PrivateRoute = (props: PrivateRouteProps) => {
    const { component: Component, context: IAuthContext, ...rest } = props;
    console.log("Private route for ", props);
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(routeProps) =>
                props.context.isAuthenticated ? (
                    <Component {...routeProps} />
                ) : (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: '/login',
                            state: { from: routeProps.location }
                        }}
                    />
                )
            }
        />
    );
};

export default withAuthContext(PrivateRoute);
```

> App.tsx

```
return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <PublicRoute path="/frame" component={Frame} exact isAuthorized={true}/>
                    <Route path="/login" component={NewLogin} exact isAuthorized={true}/>
                    <PrivateRoute path="/nav" component={NavigationBar} exact/>
                    <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={AnalyticsDashBoard} exact/>
                    <PrivateRoute path="/subscription" component={OrderSuccess} exact/>
                    <PrivateRoute path="/onboarding" component={OnBoarding} exact/>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
```

The user is already loggedin, and session persistence set to local.
The problem is, when I try localhost/subscription, which is a private route, context.isAuthenticated is false since "onAuthStateChanged" observer is not triggered yet, so its going to login page, but in few milliseconds, authStateChange triggered and context set, but its no use since application already navigated to login since privateroute thought user not loggedin.
I would like to get knowledge on how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When the page loads Firebase restores the user's credentials from local storage and checks with the server whether they are still valid. Since this is a call to the server, it may take some time and happens asynchronously. This is the reason it is normal that `firebase.auth().currentUser` is `null` until `onAuthStateChanged` fires.

The problem you have is that there are multiple reasons `firebase.auth().currentUser` can be `null`:

1. `firebase.auth().currentUser` is `null` because the client just loaded and it's still checking the credentials with the server.
2. `firebase.auth().currentUser` is `null` because the client checked the credentials against the server and the client isn't logged in.
3. `firebase.auth().currentUser` is `null` because the user never signed in, so there are no credentials to check.

You want to navigate in case 2 and 3, but not case 1.

The typical solution is to not handle navigation until the first time `onAuthStateChanged` has fired. At that point you can be certain that the credentials were checked against the server, or that there were no credentials to check, in both of which cases you'll want to navigate to the sign-in page.

---

An additional option to speed this up is to store a small token in local storage yourself when the user signs in for the first time, and then read that when the app loads. If the token is present you can distinguish between case 1 and 3, and use that to navigate to the correct page a bit sooner.

For an example of this, see this I/O talk about [Architecting Mobile Web Apps](https://youtu.be/NwY6jkohseg?t=1309).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to wait for `onAuthStateChanged()` to fire you can use a promise with async / await:

```
/** Waits for auth state to init on navigation or refresh, otherwise resolves immediately */
private async waitForAuthInit() {
  let unsubscribe: Promise<firebase.default.Unsubscribe>;
  await new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
    unsubscribe = this.auth.onAuthStateChanged((_) => resolve());
  });
  (await unsubscribe!)();
}
```

I await this function before I query for the user:

```
async getCurrentUser(): Promise<firebase.default.User | null> {
    try {
      await this.waitForAuthInit();
      return await this.auth.currentUser;
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.log('Failed to get current user...', err);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Now it's safe to query for the user on page load, without having to use callback functions, observables, subscriptions, etc. and without having to call `onAuthStateChanged()` ever again.

I should note I'm using Angular 13 and the @angular/fire dependency, which is a thin wrapper library. The syntax is probably different in other frameworks.

This is the only way I've found to contain the firestore dependency to a single service, instead of calling `onAuthStateChanged()` all over the place.

It's particularly useful for Angular AuthGuards, you can call `getCurrentUser()` without having to worry about a false negative during those initial milliseconds.

It would be nice if firebase implemented something like this on their side, so we wouldn't get false negatives when we call `auth.currentUser`, but that's none of my business...

Comment: Applied this since it looks like a convenient method but I wonder if it has any meaningful impact on page load time.

Comment: That depends what you use it for, my use case was for checking whether the page should be loaded in the first place. In other words, if you don't need the user before page load, then don't await this method before page load.

Comment: To improve performance you can always add a token to localStorage like Frank suggested above. Essentially you're trying to predict firebase's response.