# Better way to update react component on event

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm making a web-app in which I use React, together with Firebase Authentication. I have a login page and I want it to redirect to a different page when a user is already signed in.

To check if the user is logged in I use a method to retrieve the User object, it returns null when a user is not signed in and a user object with all sorts of data if they are.

I have an if statement in my render method (of the login page) which checks if the user is logged in, but I ran into an issue. When a user first loads up the page it takes around half a second for the Firebase API to retrieve the user object and until that is completed my user object will return null.

This makes for an issue where it seems as though my user isn't logged in even if they are. That causes them not to redirect and stay on the login page until the state is updated in some way after the user object is initialized.

Firebase offers a way to fix this by giving us an `onAuthStateChanged()` method which allows me to execute a function when a user signs in or logs out.

What I'm doing now is using this method in the constructor method of my Login page class to manually re-render the component, thus redirecting the user when Firebase logs them in. It looks something like this:

```
export default class Login extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props:Props) {
        super(props)

        this.props.firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            const oldState = this.state
            this.setState(oldState)
        })

    }

    render () {

        if (this.props.firebase.auth().currentUser) {
            return (
                <Redirect to="/earn" />
            )
        } else {
            return (
                // Login page
            )
        }
    }
}
```

(I omitted some irrelevant code)

Now this works fine and all but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it and I feel like I could make it look a lot nicer, I just don't know how.

Any suggestions or official ways to achieve what I'm doing right now are very much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can create an in progress state *boolean* variable which helps to render a loading icon until the code does not get back the response from the API. Usually I go with this option. In this way you don't need to redirect immediately and with an extra if statement you can show to the user that icon instead of going into that `<Redirect>` case.

Comment: What about not using `auth().currentUser` and keep the user in aa state. You can then just update the state if `onAuthStateChanged` is triggered

Comment: Basically, your component needs 2 boolean information to render correctly: "Is a user logged in?" and "Is a user being authenticated". So, you need to create a state for these 2 informations and update these states according to what happens in your app.

Comment: So I can put the `onAuthStateChanged()` listener in the constructor and it's not considered bad practice? That's the main thing I questioned myself about.

Comment: You could also move all the checking of logged in user functionality into a higher order component at the route entry, this will make the decision making and rendering of component faster and much better

Comment: You may have to pu the `onAuthStateChanged()` outside of the constructor to the `componeneDidMount()` and then set your new state from there, this is considered best practice

Comment: Beyond what others have said, There will still be a brief loading period before a user gets their logged in state. It might be a good idea to server-side render your react app if your architecture allows for it.

Comment: I helped somebody with this earlier today. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60149287/firebase-auth-currentuser-is-null-when-loading-the-page-user-loaded-when-authst/60153899#60153899