# Is it safe to store firebase user credential token on local or session storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

To increase the performance of my react app on page reload, I store user credentials on local storage and clear them on logout. But users often not logout these days and user credentials can stay in local storage for long time which I think can lead to some security leaks? I am no expert on firebase security so can someone explain if is it safe?

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
    if (user) {
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
    }
})
```

Comment: If i'm not mistaken firebase takes care of that by default. No?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On most platforms the Firebase Authentication SDK already automatically stores the user's credentials in local storage, and reloads it from there when the app restarts/page reloads. The reason you still see a delay on a page reload before `onAuthStateChanged` fires, is because the client checks with the server to see if the credentials are (still) valid.

A simple workaround to be able to act right away when the page loads, *while* Firebase is checking the credentials, is to store a value about the last known authentication state in local storage yourself and use that to determine your initial action. That's essentially what you're doing with the `user` object in your question.

There is nothing wrong with that, as long as you understand that the first time `onAuthStateChanged` fires, the data *may* be different from what you stored. It typically won't be, but it *may*, which is the whole reason Firebase has to check the credentials to begin with.

Also see my answer to this related question from yesterday: [Firebase auth.currentUser is null when loading the page, user loaded when authstatechange called after some milli seconds of page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60149287/firebase-auth-currentuser-is-null-when-loading-the-page-user-loaded-when-authst/60153899#60153899)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to change the persistent to `Persistent.SESSION`.

```js
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
```

Yes, this do not cover the whole problem (because user also may not close the browser) but it makes a sense.