# Problem with onAuthStateChanged (React & Firebase)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase and i want to solve problem with delay. When I'm refreshing currentUser is setting to null and my component is not showing but after 2 sec it is working correctly. Here is code:

Code example:

```
type FirebaseUserState = User | null;

export function useAuth() {
  let [currentUser, setUser] = useState<FirebaseUserState>(null);

  auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user !== null) {
      setUser(user);
    }
  });
  return currentUser;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this? [Firebase auth.currentUser is null when loading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60149287/13130697)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)